# open source php hotel booking system

Tags: php, open-source, lamp, looking-for-a-script

Anyone recommend a good open source hotel booking system built for a LAMP stack?

Answer (score 2):

[Posting for future reference]
It's still currently in dev status, but the Drupal [Rooms](http://drupal.org/project/rooms) project is headed this direction.

Comment: very nice. even uses commerce

Answer (score 0):

http://joomlahbs.com/ might be of help since joomla is open source

Answer (score 0):

[CultBooking](http://www.cultuzz.com/cultbooking) from Cultuzz is basic but free