# Looking for full web based booking system

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mysql

I've searched around here but could not find any booking system that would suit my need. I hope maybe you can help me out.

I've already seen [question #11379](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11379/open-source-php-hotel-booking-system). Solutions provided there are not helping and scripts not interesting.

I'm looking for a booking system that support infinite number of hotels/rooms/pricingschemes.

There should be unlimited number of hotel owner/users, who can access control panel and set availability for their hotel. Or create seasonal prices and adjust them.

I should be able to have 15% booking fee paid through credit cart. I can work on integration with my system, it just needs to have correct APi/functionality to support this.

I love wordpress so if there are some nice plugins for that, I'm open for suggestions. But this is not a must.

It should be php/mysql based as I'm not good at anything else :)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots plugins available in wordpress, joomla and drupal but i don't think it covers all of your needs. you want customize hotel booking system, as you said.

I suggest you to make a document listed all the specifications (what you want) and hire good company or programmer.

There are lots of websites availble in market,like odesk.com. Place your requirements there. Then, you'll get a stronger response there and you can choose a good one.

PHP/MySQL is a good option to build your customized hotel booking system.

**Please Consider these points**

- Good in design *(SEO Friendly)*
- Must be secure system because you deal with *online transactions*
- Must be scalable *(Future enhancement)*

Comment: if I have to program, I'd do it myself. I'm pretty good with wordpress and I can build on that. But it would be easier to find a cool framework and build on that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin that does most of what you have mentioned.

I have not included credit card payments for the reason that I'm not sure if wordpress is secure enough to keep this kind of sensitive data. I have added paypal though, and paypal does accept credit cards.

If you are still interested there is a free version here:
http://wp-easybooking.com/9-easybooking-plugin-free-.html

There is a demo here:
http://wp-easybooking.com/demo.

The free version offers:

1. Unlimited hotels
2. Unlimited Room types
3. Unlimited Hotel Owners who can edit their hotels and manage their bookings
4. All hotel owners may have unlimited hotels
5. Multilingual
6. Automatic currency conversion
7. Bookings statuses (Pending, Confirmed, Cancelled, Completed and Expired)
8. Search widget
9. Search by location or hotel name
10. Bank payment or PayPal payment available
11. Guests may view their booking's status and details on-line by using their booking number and PIN (sent by email)
12. ...and more

In a premium version (not free), the admin can create Package deals (business deals), and define the amount each hotels owes him (fee). The fee may be a periodical amount (like 100$ each month), or a percentage of bookings price (15% of months bookings), or a combination of these two charging methods.